# How can i use UISwitch to turn of local notification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, uiswitch

Can anyone help me how to use the state of a UISwitch to turn on/off local notifications declared in Appdelegate.swift ?

**Viewcontroller.swift:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!
var switchState = true
let switchKey = "switchState"

@IBAction func saveSwitchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(switchButton.on, forKey: "switchState")
}

override public func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  switchButton.on =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func handleRegionEvent(region: CLRegion) {
  // Show an alert if application is active
  if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
    if let message = notefromRegionIdentifier(region.identifier) {
      if let viewController = window?.rootViewController {
        showSimpleAlertWithTitle(nil, message: message, viewController: viewController)
      }
    }
  } else {
     // Otherwise present a local notification
     let notification = UILocalNotification()
     notification.alertBody = notefromRegionIdentifier(region.identifier)
     notification.soundName = "Default";
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to disable local notifications when `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")` is `false`?

Comment: there's no standard way to turn local notifications off, you should just ignore them when `switchState` is `false`.

Comment: Yes, when switchstate is false then local notification should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should can be accomplished using targetAction

```
   override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        switchButton.on =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchState")

        //Set button to observe target action
        switchButton.addTarget(self, action: "presentNotification", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) 
    }

    func presentNotification() {
        //Do notification stuff here

    }
```

Comment: How can i implement the code in my AppDelegate (Matthew) ? :-)

Comment: You could switch the target to an instance of your appDelegate object. But I would recommend either passing the notifications into your view controller, or redeclaring them in the view controller. `switchButton.addTarget(AppDelegate(), action: "presentNotification", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged) ` However, this approach requires that your `presentNotification` be written in the App Delegate. It also creates a new AppDelegate object which is not recommended.